# Creating Formula from Data Series

Tags: power-series, data-analysis

I have a power-law-ish data series and need to back my way into a formula for it, such that it can be generated for any number of points.  This is the n=20 version (value rounded to nearest 0.25).  Could someone provide me with a formula that fits or a pointer to how I could derive it myself?

20
10
7.5
6
5.25
4.75
4.25
3.75
3.5
3.25
3
2.75
2.5
2.5
2.25
2.25
1.75
1.75
1.5
1.5

Comment: Replacing every number with its reciprocal we get [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bestfit%20.0500,%200.100,%200.133,%200.167,%200.190,%200.211,%200.235,%200.267,%200.286,%200.308,%200.333,%200.364,%200.400,%200.400,%200.444,%200.444,%200.571,%200.571,%200.667,%200.667)

Comment: That looks interesting, thanks, can I ask why you needed to replace each number with its reciprocal?

Comment: Because of the "hyperbolic look" of your (direct) curve near $0$ (see too Claude's answer +1). The "best fit" methods proposed by CAS return usually polynomial solutions (not really good near $0$ here). Note that the reciprocal method requires a little more precision for the last (small) values. Excellent continuation,

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $x_i=i$, a scatter plot of the data reveals an hyperbolic trend. As Raymond Manzoni noticed, if we do the same using the reciprocals of the $y$'s, "almost" a linear trend seems to appear.

So, the simplest model to regress could be $$y=\frac 1{a_0+a_1x}$$ Using least squares, we get $$y=\frac{1}{0.0164378+0.0351191\, x}$$ to which corresponds a sum of squares equal to $5.7851$ and $R^2=0.9923$.

As Raymond Manzoni did, we could add more terms and fit a model $$y=\frac 1{\sum_{k=0}^n a_i x^i}$$ and, varying $n$ try to find a model. For example, using $n=2$, we should get $$y=\frac{1}{0.00898542+0.0425887\, x-0.000865475 \,x^2}$$ to which corresponds a sum of squares equal to $2.9419$ and $R^2=0.9961$.

But, in order to limit the number of parameters, we can also try something like $$y=\frac 1{a_0+a_1x^{a_2}}$$ This will lead to $$y=\frac{1}{-0.0300556+0.0802496\,x^{0.647925}}$$  to which corresponds a sum of squares equal to $1.1558$ and $R^2=0.9985$. This is quite significantly better that the previous model.

You should notice that I did not work with thre reciprocals of the $y_i$'s because what is measured is $y$ and not any of its possible transforms.